# C# Regex check if path starts with specific path but does not contain a slash after

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to Regex so please take it easy!

I need to check in C# using Regex if a folder name start with a base folder name and doesn't have any slash after the base, ie:

Base Folder: user/folder/

```
Check: user/folder/text.txt (IS VALID)
Check: user/folder/subfolder/test2.txt (Not valid since there is a slash after)
Check: user/folder/ (VALID)
Check: user/sub1/ (INVALID not same base)
```

Thanks,

```
Tried: ^(user\/local\/)[^\/]
```

But couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please specify the language/framework/platform/application with which you'll be applying your regex pattern...

Comment: Sorry, it will be done in C#

Comment: `@"^user\/folder\/(?!.*\/.*$)"` should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^              # At the beginning of the string,
user/folder/   # match 'user/folder/' literally,
[^/]*          # then 0 or more non-forward-slash character
$              # right before the end of string.
```

`/` doesn't mean anything special so there's no need to escape it.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/a0xi3h/1).

Try it [on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbwuDo).